# Assembly: why do we subtract esp if the push command already does the subtraction?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

According to disassembler, there are some functions look like

```
sub esp, 0x20
push some registers
do some stuffs
pop the registers
add esp, 0x20
ret
```

At first I thought it was to allocate memory for local variables, but I realize there are other functions look like just simply

```
push some registers
do stuffs
pop some registers
ret
```

which does not subtract esp manually.

I have done some searching and apparently the push command already automatically subtract esp for the size of the value pushed; if this is the case, then why in the first function we still need to manually subtract esp at the beginning of the function? Or in other words, what exactly is the difference in purpose between the two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts a reservation (allocation) of stack space for local variables. Also, some versions of [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) may require specific stack pointer alignment upon function entry

Comment: Why do we need to reserve the stack space if the push command already does the "reservation"?

Comment: Push command does preserve the register that has to be preserved according to used ABI

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Push command subtracts esp by 4 for each register pushed and pop adds 4 back for each register. The question is why do we subtract that extra 32 at the beginning? (There are functions that subtract 0x1C9 which is pretty large so I think it is not an alignment purpose)

Comment: Apart from changing the stack register value, the push instruction stores the content of a register on top of the stack and pop instruction restores a register from the stack.

Comment: I understand that. Let's say we have the esp equal to 0x8000 at beginning, we push eax to the stack and it becomes 0x7ffc, then after some operatios we pop eax back, causing the value of esp to come back to 0x8000. What is the problem with this? Why do we have to subtract from esp some extra numbers at the beginning?

Comment: If we need more space for local variables than we have registers available what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122341/discussion-between-cr001-and-serge).

Comment: To be complete, reservation might also be for ABI compliant register save, exception frames and nested parameters frames( and/or -pointers).

Comment: Late to the party, but I still have the same question, why do we `sub` if `push` does the "reservation" already? Also, the book Programming from the Ground Up says about this: 
>"This way, we can use the stack for variable storage without worrying about clobbering them with pushes that we may make for function calls."
I don't understand that "clobbering" part.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEid push involves memory write while subtraction from the stack pointer register does not

Comment: @Serge Yes, I do understand that difference. Now if `push` already does both the subtraction and memory writing, why do we resort to using `sub` and `mov` while `push` does both things?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEid when you need to allocate some local stack storage apart from preserve registers, then you have to do `sub` from stack pointer anyway. If you use `mov` in this case to preserve registers then you could rearrange the memory accesses and other computations to optimize the execution time.You can probably achieve the same speed with pushes, but if you need to calculate any addresses for later use relative final sp value you would make the things more complicated than they could be.